# Erro no emulador android genymotion (linux): HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1

Tags: android, flutter, genymotion

Eu tenho o seguinte erro ao executar um projeto android flutter, notei que, se eu deixar meu código sem letras no text class, o código será executado. Um exemplo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main(){
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "Count People",
      home: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(".", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          FlatButton(
              child: Text("ButtonTest", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              onPressed: (){}
          ),
        ],
      )
  ));
}
```

Observei que se eu usar "." (ponto como está no código acima), o programa executa, porém  ao colocar qualquer letra (a, b, c...), o programa até chegar a entrar no processo de implantação, mas dá um erro no emulador.

Exemplo do trecho com caracteres que causam o erro:

```
children: <Widget>[
          Text("a", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
```

Saída de erro do console:

```
    Performing hot restart...
    Syncing files to device Flutter...
    Restarted application in 2.687ms.
    F/libc    ( 2131): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xcee3f908 in tid 2148 (1.gpu)
    *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'Android/vbox86p/vbox86p:7.1.1/NMF26Q/392:userdebug/test-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'x86'
    pid: 2131, tid: 2148, name: 1.gpu  >>> br.com.myname.count_people <<<
    signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 0xcee3f908
        eax cdb8e5a8  ebx cf6fdbbc  ecx cdb8d430  edx 00000000
        esi 0000001b  edi 00000002
        xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 0000006b  xss 0000002b
        eip cee3f909  ebp cdb8d378  esp cdb8d330  flags 00010246
    backtrace:
    ...
    #61 pc 0111accf  /data/app/br.com.myname.count_people-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x10fb000)
        #62 pc 000752b2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
        #63 pc 000202ae  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
    Lost connection to device.
```

Saída de erro do terminal com o comando flutter run:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Flutter in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              1,2s
Resolving dependencies...                                           2,6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        18,0s
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...                         6,6s
I/Choreographer( 2267): Skipped 89 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Syncing files to device Flutter...                                 F/libc    ( 2267): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xcef18908 in tid 2284 (1.gpu)                      
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***                                                    
Build fingerprint: 'Android/vbox86p/vbox86p:7.1.1/NMF26Q/392:userdebug/test-keys'                                  
Revision: '0'                                                                                                      
ABI: 'x86'                                                                                                         
pid: 2267, tid: 2284, name: 1.gpu  >>> br.com.myname.count_people <<<                                        
signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 0xcef18908                                                      
    eax cdc5c5a8  ebx cf7d6bbc  ecx cdc5b430  edx 00000000                                                         
    esi 0000001b  edi 00000002                                                                                     
    xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 0000006b  xss 0000002b                                           
    eip cef18909  ebp cdc5b378  esp cdc5b330  flags 00010246                                                       
backtrace:    
...
#61 pc 0111accf  /data/app/br.com.myname.count_people-2/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x10fb000)         
    #62 pc 000752b2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)                                              
    #63 pc 000202ae  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)                                                       
Lost connection to device.                                                                                         
Could not update files on device: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri =          
http://127.0.0.1:44139/D4BNlRCD8IA=/
Syncing files to device Flutter...
```

Acho esquisito esse erro e não aceitar letras, fechando a conexão. Pesquisei bastante e vi que algumas pessoas que usam Mac OS parecem ter um erro parecido, não sei se tem haver com a base do kernel do Unix. Lá eles falavam para configurar o no_proxy. Mas realmente não tenho ideia do que seja.

Agradeço quem puder contribuir.

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta colocar um Scaffold, por que Text depende de theme, você pode implementar o theme colocando algum pre definido por exemplo:

```
Text(
'Seu texto aqui',
 style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline,
 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

ou então colocar um:

```
Material (
 child: Text(
 'Seu texto aqui',
 style: TextStyle( ...)
 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

e a forma indicada:

```
void main(){
 runApp(MaterialApp(
   title: "Count People",
   home: Scaffold(
     body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(".", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: 
      FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      FlatButton(
          child: Text("ButtonTest", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          onPressed: (){}
      ),
    ],
  )
 ));
}
```